# QR code is not loading

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, qr-code

I tried to connect Whatsapp on chrome. But when I go to https://web.whatsapp.com, QR code doesn't load. Rather it shows a continuously moving circle.

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: ***** My problem was in an adware called "Superfish" that came with my brand new Lenovo Y50. I removed it and got the QR right away

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you use the QR reader build in Whatsapp and not an separated app.
You can access the QR reader in Whatsapp by entering the menu at the main screen.
If `Whatsapp Web` doesn't show up in the menu list then you either haven't installed the latest version of Whatsapp or you have to reboot your device in order to make it appear in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Right, that sounds to me like you might have a slow internet connection resulted by too many users online at the time or various other reasons.

I am assuming you are talking about the mobile version of Chrome (or do you mean the computer version)? This will work either way:

Try to restart your browser and making sure all add-ons and browser updates etc. are up-to-date. Close unnecessary tabs.

THEN:
You should just select the URL in the browser window and hitting 'ENTER' to "hard refresh" the page.

If you are on mobile data, try this on WIFI as it will be faster in most cases.

Comment: It is not the internet, it is Chrome. I tried with Firefox and it loads straightaway.